# How to preprocessing sequential data for 2D-CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is there any way to transform sequential data to 2-dimensional data in order to use it for a common CNN?

My dataset Looks like: 14,40,84,120,38,29,395,58,153,...

But I need a 2-dimensional representation for that. Is there any established algorithm for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really sure that a CNN is what you want? It might not be the best choice for sequential data. If you want to learn more about alternative ways to deal with sequential data (like time series), I recommend reading the paper "[The Great Time Series Classification Bake Off](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01711)".

I especially recommend looking into [Dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) first. It might not be a bleeding edge deep learning algorithm but turns out to be very hard to beat when it comes to classifying sequential data.

Comment: Thanks for the links. That answers my questions. Yes I am sure - it is part of my Research. Already used other algorithms for that.

Comment: What makes you say that CNN may not be the best choice for sequential data? More recently it has been discussed as a better alternative to LSTM/RNN. At the very least it should be considered equally to recurrent methods. I suggest researching Dilated Causal CNN with Attention.

Comment: @ChrisFarr You're absolutely right that attention based CNNs might be an alternative these days. However, I was under the impression that the OP wanted to use "common CNNs" only.